# I do not have outlook installed in my Window Machine. How to send mail using powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I wrote one script using powershell for my work and I want to send the output every time the script run. Problem is that I do not have Outlook installed on my Window machine. Is there a way to send email using powershell without having outlook installed on Window Machine ? I am using powershell v2 /v3 .

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `send-mailmessage` commandlet to send emails from a powershell script. No need for a dedicated mail client.

[Technet Send-MailMessage](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh849925.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. Let me check this function.

Comment: It's asking for smtp server name. I need to figure it out as the Window machine is handled by our Window team.

Comment: you will need an smtp server if you want to send mails. If this is a work project and your company can send and receive emails, they must have an smtp server. So ask your IT colleagues to provide you with server name and authentication details, if necessary. This is not something you can somehow figure out.